# Mysql консоль время выполнения запроса

Tags: mysql

К примеру есть запрос вида

```
SELECT * FROM cities WHERE latitude BETWEEN '52' AND '53';
```

Консоль мне пишет

> 52427 rows in set (0.61 sec)

Т.е. время выполнения запроса меньше секунды, но на самом деле он выполнялся минут 5. Это нормальное поведение ?

Comment: Попробуйте вместо * использовать count (*) и посмотреть сколько времени уйдет

Comment: Так вобще одну запись выбирает - 1 row in set (0.03 sec)

Comment: Все верно, запись одна, а по времени сколько?

Comment: 0.03 sec Как такое может быть ? Что-то я запутался совсем.

Comment: Я просто веду к тому, что у вас все эти 54 тыс строк выводятся в консоль. Вот пока все выведется вы и ждёте

Comment: Спасибо ! Совсем забыл про это...